# VSCode adding a ruler for python files but not C files. Why?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm tring to add custom rulers for C and python files in vscode. Here is my settings.json file

```
{
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Path\\to\\my\\python.exe",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "[C_Cpp]": {
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.rulers": [
            88
        ],
    },
}
```

Here's my main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Rulers correctly show up for .py files but .c .C .cpp .Cpp files don't show the expected ruler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
"[cpp]": {
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
    },
```

I guess it overrides the config for a language, and not an extension, as when you put the cursor on the word, the following popup appears:[image]

Comment: Using "[c]" or "[cpp]" worked! ("[C]" and "[Cpp]" and "[c_cpp]" didn't)